# Spring roo one to many not sorted

Tags: hibernate, sorting, spring-roo

The default one to many relationship in Spring Roo has a Set variable for maintaining relations data.

```
public Set<MyChildObject> Parent.getChildren() {
    return this.children;
}
```

when I try to use this in my JSPX file, the data is not sorted.

```
<c:forEach items="${parent.children}" var="item">
    <c:out value="${item.id}  " />
</c:forEach>
```

What would be a better and easier way to sort the data either in JSPX or Domain? please provide a working example.

Comment: Sets are not sorted.  If you want a sorted Collection, you need to use List.  This will sort by whatever criteria the DB uses by default, usually the primary key and any indexes you have setup.  If you want to force the sort order, you can use the (at)OrderColumn annotation to instruct which column and direction to sort the list.

Comment: well this is the default implementation of spring roo one-to-many getter function that returns a set.

Comment: You can modify the generated Java code that Roo creates.  In fact, you are almost expected to do so.  As long as the Roo Shell is running, it will identify that the .java file was updated, and change the getters/setters accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you only have it like a method. You should have a variable:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "the relationship in the other class Ithink it could be for you parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true)
public Set<MyChildObject> child= new HashSet<MyChildObject>();
```

and the you must put this in the show.jspx:

```
    <field:display field="child" id="your child id" object="${the class}" z="your chid z"/>
```

Comment: I think it would still not be sorted.  Sets, by definition, are unsorted, with the exception of SortedSet.  Internally, I believe Spring, and by extension Roo, is creating a Proxy object wrapping a Set (for lazy loading and such).  I am not saying it's impossible it's not a SortedSet of some kind, just that I don't believe it is.

Comment: Well I had to change the getter function and return the sorted list using Comparator and TreeSet.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
@OrderBy("orderingField asc")
```

and don't forget to

```
import javax.persistence.OrderBy;
```